# How to install git lfs

Tags: linux, git, shell, ssh

I am trying to clone a git repository using command:

```
git clonerepo test_simrkaur
```

But getting this error:

```
[simrkaur@bhlinb40 Repos]$ git clonerepo test_simrkaur
Cloning into 'test_simrkaur'...
remote: Counting objects: 2, done
remote: Total 431 (delta 0), reused 431 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (431/431), 128.85 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (74/74), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
git-lfs smudge -- 'testlfs.txt': git-lfs: command not found
error: external filter git-lfs smudge -- %f failed -1
error: external filter git-lfs smudge -- %f failed
fatal: testlfs.txt: smudge filter lfs failed
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'
```

I tried running command 'git checkout -f HEAD' but still getting the error:

```
[simrkaur@bhlinb40 test_simrkaur]$ git checkout -f HEAD
git-lfs smudge -- 'testlfs.txt': git-lfs: command not found
error: external filter git-lfs smudge -- %f failed -1
error: external filter git-lfs smudge -- %f failed
fatal: testlfs.txt: smudge filter lfs failed
```

I think, I have to install git lfs. But dont know how can I install it using ssh commands.

Please help!

Comment: For Amazon Linux 2, you can follow the steps explained here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71466001/12326605

Answer (score 13):

On linux system, you can install it like this

```
sudo apt-get install git-lfs
```

If you are using Windows, then follow this: https://git-lfs.github.com/

Answer (score 3):

Download and install the Git command line extension. Once downloaded and installed, set up Git LFS for your user account by running:

`git lfs install`

You only need to run this once per user account.

Reference: https://git-lfs.github.com/

Comment: > You only need to run this once per user account.

In fact the documentation says

You only have to do this once per  repository per machine.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, you can do:

```
brew install git-lfs
git lfs install
```