# Git Large File Storage / How to install git lfs on AWS EC2 Linux 2 / "No package git-lfs available."

Tags: linux, git, amazon-ec2, git-lfs

How to install `git-lfs` on an Amazon EC2 (Amazon Linux 2) instance?

Based on https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/INSTALLING.md did I tried:

```
sudo yum install git -y;
cd /home/ec2-user;
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/github/git-lfs/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash
   -> which tells me afterwards: 
   The repository is setup! You can now install packages.
sudo yum install git-lfs
   -> gives me: 
   Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
   No package git-lfs available.
   Error: Nothing to do
```

---

Future commands (not possible yet duo `git: 'lfs' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.` after `git lfs install`) would than be based on https://git-lfs.github.com/

```
git lfs install
...
git clone https://yourrepo.git;
```

---

Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM) - Kernel 5.10, SSD Volume Type / Arm

Comment: did you try running `yum update/upgrade` before? I don't have an EC2 instance to test, but I used the amazonlinux docker image and I was able to install following your instructions.

Comment: @JuanFontes Thank you for the hint, unfortunately do I still get "No package git-lfs available." on the EC2 instance itself. :/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With Amazon Linux 2, you can use the **Extras** Library to install application and software updates on your instances. These software updates are known as topics.

Below are the steps:

1. Connect to your EC2 Linux instance using SSH.
2. Use the **which** command to confirm that the amazon-linux-extras package is installed:

```
    $ which amazon-linux-extras

    /usr/bin/amazon-linux-extras
```

If the amazon-linux-extras package isn't installed, you can use yum to install it:

```
$ sudo yum install -y amazon-linux-extras
```

To list the available topics, you can use the following command:

```
$ amazon-linux-extras list
```

3. `git-lfs` usually comes as part of the epel-release, so you need to first to install epel release for Amazon Linux:

```
    $ sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
```

For the Amazon Linux AMI, access to the Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL) repository is configured, but it is not enabled by default.

```
    $ sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel
```

4. Now you can install `git-lfs` or whatever else you like from epel-release:

```
    $ sudo yum install git-lfs
```

Comment: If you get `/var/lang/bin/python: No module named amazon_linux_extras`, you may need to force amazon-linux-extras to use Python 2 if Python 3 is installed: `PYTHON=python2 amazon-linux-extras install epel -y` [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69614110).

Comment: If you get `/bin/sh: yum-config-manager: command not found` you may need to install `yum-utils` first: `yum install -y yum-utils`

Comment: This worked on Amazon Sagemaker Notebook instances as well.

Answer (score 5):

As described on packagecloud[1], you need to run:

```
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/github/git-lfs/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash
```

to install the dependencies and the repos. Alternatively you can take the script from [1] directly. You can then simply install with yum:

```
sudo yum install git-lfs
```

[1] https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/install#bash-rpm

Comment: Thank you @Thomas for your response. Did you tested it on an AWS EC2? Your code lines are the exact same lines I mentioned in the problem description. And still don't work for me yet. :/

Comment: @MJey yep tested and worked. Maybe include your error message in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to directly install the ARM64 git-lfs binaries:

```
wget https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/releases/download/v3.1.2/git-lfs-linux-arm64-v3.1.2.tar.gz

sudo yum install git -y

tar -xvf git-lfs-linux-arm64-v3.1.2.tar.gz

sudo ./install.sh

git lfs install
```

Now, enjoy your GIT-LFS on ARM64.